# Sitecore website: show/hide menu items based on logged in user role

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, roles, sitecore7.2

I'm building a sitecore 7.2 using asp.net MVC 5.0. The site will have login and each user will be roles.

We need to show/hide the site menu items based on logged in user Roles. The user detail and roles are stored in SAP backend.

Could someone please advise what's the best way to achieve above?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you will want to map the roles stored in your backend system to Sitecore Roles. Potentially look into creating a custom Role Provider (see in document below)

Once logged in, requests are made to Sitecore are made in context of that logged in user. Therefore if the user, or their role, does not have permission to view an Item, it will not be returned in the request. This effect means that your Menu will not display items they do not have permission to access.

You and Content Editors can control what users and roles can access via the Security Editor and view their access rights via the Access Viewer in the Content Editor.

This documents will have everything you need - http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_usletter.pdf
http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/securityadministratorscookbook-usletter.pdf

Its also worth noting that Sitecore's seucirty manages roles as Ors. So if one of the user's role has permission to see an Item, then the user can see it.

If you require the roles to be Ands; every role must have permission before its displayed to the user, check this post out - http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2015/03/require-membership-in-multiple-roles-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Comment: What if you are not logged in and what to hide all the member related menu items?

Comment: That is quite simple under the assumption they also shouldn't be able to access the item as well. In the Security Editor select the Default/Anonymous user and tick all the items they should not have read access. This is because in Sitecore not logged in users are assigned to the user account *DOMAIN OF SITE*/Anonymous

Answer (score 1):

You need the roles for the current user from SAP? There is an Odata API for that: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/4c/5bde6197817511e10000000a42189b/content.htm

You could query the API in real-time, but it would of course require a login to SAP for the current user.

Or - you could use another API and connect via a service user.